# SQL query to change file extension in a record containing a file-path?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given an SQL table `Table` with a column `path`, how can I modify values like `/dir/subdir/file.aaa` => `/dir/subdir/file.bbb` e.g. modify just the file-extension without having to hard-code the specific file/path into my query?

Answer (score 1):

If the column only contains values that are structured like a file, path the following will work:

```
update the_table
   set path = replace(path, '.aaa', '.bbb')
where path like '%.aaa';
```

Note that this will also update a value like `/dir/subdir.aaa/file.aaa` to `/dir/subdir.bbb/file.bbb`.

Another option is to use a regular expression:

```
update foo 
  set file_path = regexp_replace(file_path, '\.aaa$', '.bbb', 1, 0, 'i')
where lower(file_path) like '%.aaa';
```

Comment: IIRC this would be case sensitive, is there an easy way around that? e.g. .txt and .TXT should both be matched

Answer (score 1):

Seems a perfect fit for  [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) :

```
with t as (select '/dir/subdir/file.aaa' as path from dual
           union all select '/dir/subdir.aaa/file.aaa' from dual)

select regexp_replace(path, '[.][^.]*$', '.bbb') path
--          ^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^
--        replace     last dot-whatever   by the "right" extension
from t
where path like '%.aaa'
--               ^^^^^
--    only for path ending with the "wrong" extension
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37017 for some tests